# How to find current logged in user in Rodauth (Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rodauth gem in our project, and I need to find what type of the user is logged in and display different webpage based on that fact.

However, I can't find a way to check which user is logged in. I looked everywhere in Rodauth document. I know other gem has this feature but I did not find any useful information for this gem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/janko/rodauth-rails#current-account

```rb
rodauth.rails_account
```

or more-conveniently in `ApplicationController`:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private

  def current_account
    rodauth.rails_account
  end
  helper_method :current_account
end
```